# if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) not getting state value

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

**From this ajax function i am populated first drop down list first_state.php**
**below are the part of full code**

```
function showUser(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","get_district.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

### **here i am calling function and getting value of first drop down list**

```
<form class="form2" name="form_pin" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<select name="state"  onchange="showUser(this.value)">
<option value="">Select State</option>
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){                          
echo "<option value='".$row['State']."'>".$row['State']."</option>";}
</form>
```

**when calling below function i am not getting value of district**

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
{
$state = $_POST["state"];
$district = $_POST["district"];
echo $state; echo $district;        
}
```

### **the second drop down list populated when passing varable to get_district.php**

```
<?php
include_once "connect_db.inc";
$q = $_GET['q'];
//echo $q;
$con = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbusername, $dbuserpassword);
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }

mysqli_select_db($con,$default_dbname);
$sql="SELECT DISTRICT FROM state_district WHERE STATE = '".$q."'";
//$sql="SELECT * FROM state_district";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
?>
<select name="district">
<?PHP
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
     echo "<option value='".$row['DISTRICT']."'>".$row['DISTRICT']."</option>";
  }
?>
</select>
<?PHP
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

how do i take _post['district'] and _post['state'] in one form, the above code is working fine, but i am clueless. the problem is i have two php file**

Comment: HI, Where do You have something called txtHint. There is any in form named form_pin. Where do you put response from ajax?

Comment: actually i donot know how to put response from ajax

Comment: Are there any JS errors ? I suposse that you have some errors in your showUser JS function

Comment: no, actually when i select state drop down it will show district from mysql. but i want state and district value in single isset so that i insert value in mysql based on it

Comment: from above there is two php file one having ajax and state dropdown list and other populating district

Comment: So you have somewhere in your code element with `id='txtHint'`. Is this another form ? It's difficult to say something without seeing all the html code and forms structures. Maybe we can talk on [chat]

Comment: too bad we can move this to chat. Could you paste some code with form which is submitted ?

Comment: i donot have more reputation to start chat in stack overflow, i have skype id : amitsoni_us@yahoo.com

Comment: <div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here.</b></div> inside this the drop down district is coming

Comment: I'm trying to chat with skype. My skype name michal_sojka. I have send some contact request to you

Comment: thanks, the id=txtHint is the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
**You are not requesting the below code** 
------------------

<select name="district">
<?PHP
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
     echo "<option value='".$row['DISTRICT']."'>".$row['DISTRICT']."</option>";
  }
?>
</select>
-----------------------------

**to do so add ID with <select id="txtHint"></select> option in first_step.php**     
--------------------------
<form class="form2" name="form_pin" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<select name="state"  onchange="showUser(this.value)">
<option value="">Select State</option>
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){                          
echo "<option value='".$row['State']."'>".$row['State']."</option>";}
**// add below**
<select id="txtHint"></select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace $_post with $_get in your function file